# How to convert string to date and perform actions before converting back to string?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Just have a little question in regards to setting a string property value into date format, perform an date action and then revert the property value back to a string.

The plan is that I have a property known as `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "LastModifiedDateTo")` which variable is test 2. Currently the value for this is 20170203 but this can be any dynamic value.

What I want to do is that if the if statement condition is true:

- grab the property value for `testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "LastModifiedDateTo")` (don't grab def test1 the variable because I actually want the property value to change within custom properties)
- convert the string value `20170203`  into a date format '2017-02-03'
- Add the next day to the date so that it's now '2017-02-04'
- convert the date back to string format '20170204' and set the property value

Below I just have a hard coded value in the if statement as what I require for the finished value but I want that replaced to follow the method above. Can somebody help me on how to complete the conversion and set date please.

```
def test1 = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "LastModifiedDateTo")
def test2 = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "LastModifiedTimeFrom")
def test3 = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "LastModifiedTimeTo")

log.info test1
log.info test2
log.info test3

if (test2 == "23:50:00" && test3 == "00:00:00") {
   testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "LastModifiedDateTo", "20170204")
   log.error "true"
} else {
   log.error "false"
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? getting the date, changing format and not sure what you need to with changed formation. Can you please clarify? You may also find Opal answer solves your issue.

Comment: @Rao I just want a day added for the property value 'LastmodifiedDateTo' when the if condition is met

Comment: You mentioned to change format to `yyyy-MM-dd`? So, not needed really? does other properties needed too? not sure of relevance from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format doesn't matter in general, what you want to do is to add a day to given date. It can be dane in the following way (with [`TimeCategory`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html)):

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def date = Date.parse('yyyyMMdd', '20170203')

use(TimeCategory) {
    date = date + 1.day
}

assert date.format('yyyyMMdd') == '20170204'
```

Comment: can you reconfigure you answer to match my example because i've tried a lot of things and cannot get it to work

Comment: It work Opal, sorry about that, managed to refactor to how i needed it. thank you very much for your answer